# How display data generated by Rich Text Editor in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, html-entities, rich-text-editor

I'd like to use CKEditor on my site- it's generating content in HTML, which I wanna pass from database later, into the view. Unfortunately, during passing model into the view, ASP.NET is converting the HTML tags into HTML entities- how to disable that, and pass plain HTML to my view? Or should I do this in a completely different way?

Comment: Have you tried using `@Html.Raw()`?

Comment: Thank you, that solved the problem!